Create a paused/draft subscription with Stripe API?
I need a way to create a subscription for a customer, but have the subscription in a paused or draft state, so that the user isn't charged until I manually "approve" the subscription.
The subscription will be created between a customer and a stripe connect account if it matters.
Is there any way to achieve this with the Stripe API?

The best way to accomplish this is to create the Subscription with a trial and then once you "approve" the Subscription you update it to end the trial (using trial_end: 'now'), otherwise you cancel the Subscription.

This will make the subscription active and give access to whatever service it's linked to it though.

Nope, this will put the Subscription in trialing and you can not provision access until it actually moves to active (when you end the trial).

That would mean I can't use trials for their intended purpose
